# MonoTouch: RegisterClassForCellReuse in UITAbleView throws NSInvalidArgumentException

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios

I'm trying to register my own class in a tableView so I could use the internal cell pool, but it crashes at the second I try to invoke this

```
this._cellIdentifier = new NSString(VignetteCell.vignetteIdentifier);
this._photosListTableView.RegisterClassForCellReuse(typeof(UITableViewCell), this._cellIdentifier);
```

I also tried with using "typeof(VignetteCell)" but it fails also. The weird thing is that it doesn't crash on the simulator.

This is what I get:

```
[ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: MonoTouch.Foundation.MonoTouchException: Objective-C exception thrown.  Name: NSInvalidArgumentException Reason: -[UITableView registerClass:forCellReuseIdentifier:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1cf3800
at MonoTouch.UIKit.UITableView.RegisterClassForCellReuse (IntPtr cellClass, MonoTouch.Foundation.NSString reuseIdentifier) [0x00027] in /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/monotouch/src/UIKit/UITableView.g.cs:743 
at MonoTouch.UIKit.UITableView.RegisterClassForCellReuse (System.Type cellType, MonoTouch.Foundation.NSString reuseIdentifier) [0x00000] in /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/monotouch/src/UIKit/UITableView.cs:34 
...
```

I just find nothing on Google mentioning it, as if I were the only guy on this planet who tried that!

Anyway, thanks for your help!

[Edit]

Solution: In fact, it just doesn't work on iOS 5. I tried it on my iPhone 5 and it just work fine.

Comment: Can you provide your VignetteCell class? How is that type declared?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/q5XaNq2A

Should I do something else? Is using the "Register" annotation enough?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What device/simulator are you running this on? Since this is a iOS 6 specific feature, it will need to be running on iOS 6 and running on iOS 5 will cause the following error message.

Comment: No problem, you'll want to mark the answer as correct so others know that the answer has been resolved.